# opening pictures after compiling in cx_Freeze

Tags: python, compilation, pygame, png, cx-freeze

I was trying to convert a pygame game using `cx_Freeze` and when I tried to run it, the program could not open a background picture. Here is the error message:

```
Traceback <most recent call last>:
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscrips\Console.py", line 27, in <module>
        exec<code, m.__dict__>
    File "StartGame.py", line 46, in <module>
pygame.error: Couldn't open background1.png
```

and here is my `setup.py`:

```
import cx_Freeze

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("StartGame.py")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name="The Tragic Tale of Romeo and Juliet",
    options={"build.exe": {"packages":["pygame"], "include_files":["Background1.png"]}},

    executables = executables

    )
```

Answer (score 2):

You should put your all packages in the same folder with your main exe. file. If they are not in the same directory, your program can't find them.

Also setup.py must be like this;

```
from cx_Freeze import setup,Executable
setup(name="My game",
         version="1.0",
         options={"build_exe":{"packages":["pygame"],"include_files":["mypicture.png","mysecondpicture.png"]}},
         description="My game!",
         executables=[Executable("filename.py")])
```

`include_files` for packages like pictures,sounds etc.

Comment: both StartGame and Background1 are in the same file folder. I am fairly certain that it compiled with all of the other files

Comment: import cx_Freeze

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("StartGame.py")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name="The Tragic Tale of Romeo and Juliet",
    options={"build.exe": {"packages":["pygame"], "include_files":["Background1.png"]}},

    executables = executables

    )

Comment: This is my setup.py, will this work for what I am doing?

Comment: @ChrisWinjum Use my answer please, try with this one first.